# How to get the font size parameter passed to the main standard classes?

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontsize, document-classes, lengths

For complex length manipulation (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487356/problem-with-vertical-alignment-of-a-multicolumn-listing-in-a-tcolorbox)), I would need to get the font size that was passed as an option to the document class:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newlength{\mainfontsize}
\setlength{\mainfontsize}{\@ptsize}
```

I would like it to work on all the main classes including `beamer` and `extarticle`. Currently this fails on `beamer`. How to make it work? (and I don't want the exact size of the font like `10.95pt` for `11pt`, I want the option that was passed).

Comment: Perhaps related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73079/121799 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since most classes define their own option handling system you need one different macro for each.

For example, for `12pt`, `article` (and the standard LaTeX classes) store just `2` in `\@ptsize`. `extarticle` stores `12`. `beamer` stores `{size12.clo}` in a `\beamer@size` macro, and `memoir` stores `12` in `\@memptsize`. Not exactly standardised.

Here's a macro that checks for these classes and uses the correct macro accordingly, then stores the font size (from the option, not the actual font size) in a length:

```latex
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\deffontsize}[1]{%
  \setlength#1%
    {%
      \vincent@ifclassloaded {beamer}
        \get@beamersize
        {%
          \vincent@ifclassloaded {memoir}
            \get@memoirsize
            {%
              \vincent@ifclassloaded {extarticle}
                \get@extartsize
                \get@standardsize
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
\def\vincent@ifclassloaded#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname ver@#1.cls\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
\def\get@beamersize{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\get@@beamersize
  \expandafter\@firstofone\beamer@size}
\def\get@@beamersize size#1.clo{#1 pt}
\def\get@memoirsize{\@memptsize pt}
\def\get@extartsize{\@ptsize pt}
\def\get@standardsize{1\@ptsize pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newlength\mainfontsize
\deffontsize{\mainfontsize}
\the\mainfontsize
\end{document}
```

For other classes you'd need to add another conditional and the corresponding macro to get the option.